# Google drive API throwing 401 Unauthorized when authenticated with firebase node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to upload file to google drive with Google Drive API. For API use I reauthenticate using following code.

Auth code

```
const auth = getAuth();
auth.useDeviceLanguage();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

...
signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

Auth also shows consent screen. But when I try to upload file, I get 401.

```
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(
    "metadata",
    new Blob([JSON.stringify({ name: file.name, mimeType: "audio/*", parents: [ROOT_FOLDER_ID] })], {
      type: "application/json",
    }),
  );
  formData.append("file", file);
  // const token = await getToken();
  const token = (await user?.getIdToken()) || null;
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&supportsAllDrives=true`,
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      method: "POST",
      onUploadProgress(e: any) {
        setProgress((e.progress || 0) * 100);
        // fileObj.progress = Math.floor((e.progress || 0) * 100);
        // fileObj.uploadSpeed = e.rate || 0;
      },
    },
  );
```

I have checked that token is not null. What am I doing wrong?